Washing machine leak. Not the front filter
https://imgur.com/a/1bZ9Qrl
I am stumped. Besides hiring someone to start taking it apart does anyone see the issue. I have a picture of the leak when I tilted the machine up from the back.

I would start by tightening those clamps on the black tubing a bit, maybe a turn at a time.  Check the flexible black hose for pinhole leaks.  Tighten all inlet hose connections.  A small leak like that, almost need to watch/see where the water comes from when happening.  A decent phone or inspection camera might help to see.

How old is this machine? Is the water puddling just on one side? Is this gray water? I have owned LG Front Load machines since 2005 and the most problems I had was with the black flexible hose from the tub to the drain pump on the righthand side as shown in your video. It develops cracks along the seam. All of the connections on the interior use spring loaded clips, so tightening can only go so far.
